# Make date readable by R

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataset right now formatted for example as "Aug-19" which represents 08/01/2019 in mm/dd/yyyy format. How do I convert this into a format that can be read by R?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` package.

```
dates <- c("Aug-19", "Sep-19")

dates_myd <- paste0(dates, "-01")

lubridate::myd(dates_myd)
```

Comment: Will I be able to run a regression model for example with this new dates vector on the x-axis? Is this format of "Aug-19-01" recognized by R?

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate` we can also do

```
myd(dates, truncated = 1)
#[1] "2019-08-01" "2019-09-01"
```

#### data

```
dates <- c("Aug-19", "Sep-19")
```